# RxJava2. Process different properties of the object from the list

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Assume

1. There is a class **User** with two properties **name** and **age**
2. We get a list of users
3. We need to process both properties of every user.

Is it possible at all to process both properties of every user?

The following code is not correct, I know. but how to make it correct? Maybe there are any operators to get it work?

```
Observable.fromIterable(users)
    .map(user -> user.name)
    .map(string -> new NameVM(string))
    .map(user -> user.age)
    .map(int -> new AgeVM(int))
```

I have only one idea, but I don't like it much

```
Observable.fromIterable(users)
    .doOnNext(user -> new NameVM(string))
    .map(user -> user.age)
    .map(int -> new AgeVM(int))
```

Comment: Should the processing of name and age be done at the same type async? What are the results of the name / age process -> returntype?

Comment: Just modified my question by returning someVM.

Comment: Would it be enough to process both and then return a new Container containing the result of both? In the next operator you would have result from NameVM and AgetVM?

Comment: actually ended up with the Container-Solution, but a bit simpler than in your answer

Answer (score 1):

You could just process both properties as Singles and zip the result together and flatMap it with flatMapSingle. In doOnNext you would a Container for each zip.

```
@Test
  void name2() throws Exception {
    List<User> users =
        Arrays.asList(
            new User("hans", 30), new User("leon", 66), new User("Uwe", 45), new User("Michi", 23));

    Observable<Container> containerObservable =
        Observable.fromIterable(users)
            .flatMapSingle(
                user -> {
                  Single<ProcessedAge> processedAgeSingle = processeAge(user.age);
                  Single<ProcessedUserName> processedUserNameSingle =
                      processeUserName(user.userName);

                  return Single.zip(
                      processedAgeSingle,
                      processedUserNameSingle,
                      (age, name) -> {
                        return new Container(age, name);
                      });
                })
            .doOnNext(System.out::println);

    containerObservable.test().await().assertValueCount(4);
  }

  private Single<ProcessedAge> processeAge(int age) {
    return Single.just(new ProcessedAge());
  }

  private Single<ProcessedUserName> processeUserName(String userName) {
    return Single.just(new ProcessedUserName());
  }

  class User {
    String userName;
    int age;

    public User(String userName, int age) {
      this.userName = userName;
      this.age = age;
    }
  }

  class ProcessedUserName {}

  class ProcessedAge {}

  class Container {
    ProcessedUserName userNameResult;
    ProcessedAge ageResult;

    public Container(ProcessedAge age, ProcessedUserName name) {
      this.userNameResult = name;
      this.ageResult = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Container{" + "userNameResult=" + userNameResult + ", ageResult=" + ageResult + '}';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do , but from the question I think you have an observable of list of `users` and you need to process `name`  and `age` of every user and finally consume the updated `user` data.  For this why can't you use a single `map` operator

```
        Observable.fromIterable(users)
            .map(user -> {
                user.name =//do something with name);
                user.age = // do something with age);
                return user;
            }).subscribe(user -> {
                // here you get the result with processed user object
            });
```

Comment: It is totally not recommanded to modify the object in one pipeline-step. You should create a new one and pass it down, or use doOnNext for side-effects. But remember, that objects passed through the pipeline-steps should be immutable.

Comment: Sorry, the question was not clear. I don't want to modify user object, but instead to create to separate objects from name and age. See my modification

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a container solution

```
class ContainerVM {
    public NameVM nameVM;
    public AgeVM ageVM;
}

Observable.fromIterable(users)
    .map(user -> buildContainerVM(user));

private ContainerVM buildContainerVM(User user) {
    ContainerVM containerVM = new ContainerVM();
    containerVM.nameVM = new NameVM(user.name);
    containerVM.ageVM = new AgeVM(user.age);
}
```